# Where is the appropriate place to ask questions about scientific writing?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I have a few questions about writing scientific papers, but I don't know which of Science stackexchanges to ask in (could I ask in any of them?) or whether there is somewhere else more appropriate for my question(s).

Comment: [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) accepts questions about technical writing. Please be more specific about what your question is and tag it with [tag:site-recommendation].